# calling a function into another function

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote a function:

```
def spA(Beta, Alpha):
        spA = np.zeros((1,3))
        spA[0][0] = 1./rab*(-math.cos(math.radians(Beta))*math.cos(math.radians(Alpha)))
        return spA
```

and I made an attempt to call it into another function:

```
def spB(Beta, Alpha, PHI):
        spB = np.zeros((1,3))
        spA = np.zeros((1,3))
        spC = np.zeros((1,3))

        spA = spA(Beta, Alpha)
        return -(spA + spC)
```

when I call the spB function I'm obtaining the error message:

```
spA = spA(Beta, Alpha)
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

May anybody elaborate what I am doing wrong, please?
Everything works just fine when I call the spA function outside the spB one.

Comment: spA is two differents things here : a function and a array. change one of the names .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two things called `spA`; the numpy zeros array, and the function. Call one of them something different.